# Upload image from ios application to server

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiapplication

I am working on one application in which i want to save image directly on the server path. I am using below code for it but it is not saving image on that path.
Response from server is coming NUll and not savig image in server path

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
// setting up the URL to post to
NSString *urlString = @"http://192.0.168.109/Mobile_tutor/webservice/images/questions/";

// setting up the request object now
request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

/*
 add some header info now
 we always need a boundary when we post a file
 also we need to set the content type

 You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same
 as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
 */
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
 now lets create the body of the post
 */
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"--response string -%@",returnString);
```

Comment: Give details on what is and isn't working, what errors do you get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use AFNetworking so you don't have to digg into the multi-part request format.

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.0.168.109"]];
NSDictionary *simpleParams = @{ @"key": @"value" };
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/Mobile_tutor/webservice/images/questions/" parameters: simpleParams constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData
                                    name:@"paramName"
                                fileName:@"filename.png"
                                mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }];
```

Then create an operation depending on the expected response. For example if you expect JSON:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

    // handle success

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

    // handle error

}];
```

You can get more information in the [AFNetworking documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/).